# Wordpress & jQuery Responsive Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with the wordpress and with Jquery.
I have this code to show and hide a responsive navigation on the left :

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){ if ($('.responsive__menu').hasClass('is-open')) {
$('.responsive__menu').removeClass('is-open');
$('.menu').removeClass('is-active');} else {
$('.responsive__menu').addClass('is-open');
$('.menu').addClass('is-active');}});
```

It works with my website without Wordpress, but once in Wordpress, it seems that half of the code works : the creation of the cross to close the menu except that the menu does not appear.

Can you enlighten me on some points?

1. The script is loaded, are there a faster and easier way to transform the code with jquery and toogle () ?
2. It can only be a trouble about code but why it does not work anymore once on Wordpress ?

Thanks a lot for your help, before asking the question I tried many things. ^^

Answer (score 0):

If it works with any of your websites means the code is good, just you might have conflicts in your css, so include your css which is menu related last, and if it doesn't work either, post your css code, so we could see better what's going on, and there is not need for so much code. Initialize your menu without class .open , in your html and use JQUERY:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){
$(".responsive_menu).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I give you my css and I put it into wordpress like this : <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "<= get_stylesheet_uri ();?>" /> ... thanks !

Comment: @Ralph what does get_stylesheet_uri() do, and what is <= inside href shoud be <?php and please if you can, place a fiddle so i can easier edit your code

Comment: @Ralph you will have to embedd example of php output, cuz jsfiddle doesn't support php

Comment: No you didn't look there can't be any php :) you must do direct embedd of what is outputed as page, so go to your page locally, and then save html of your page, open it in notepad or whatever editor you have :) and then simply copy all html in html content, don't take links to css, already copy content of those css files into css, and jquery leave as it is :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9omwuz27/ ... does it work now ? But as you can see the JS works here .. but once in Wordpress no :/ Thanks a lot

Comment: now one more question, is that all css you have on that page , i mean all stylesheets are here in css, and they are in same order as here, and did you include jquery <script src="jquery.com...."></script> and do you get any errors in console, try to open console and see if it shows something, then answer to my comment :)

Comment: This is just style about menu and jquery and there are no errors in the console :/

Comment: is this last css in html document if not it must be last

Comment: I don't understand you want to see all my CSS ?

Comment: Nope, just is this css included last in your document

Answer (score 0):

jQuery comes with wordpress in non-conflict mode , to make sure everything works you should use jQuery variable instead of the $ variable.

you can alternatively do the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // $ variable can be used here 
  $('.menu').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.responsive__menu').hasClass('is-open')) {
      $('.respons__menu').removeClass('is-open');
      $('.menu').removeClass('is-active');
    } else {
      $('.responsive__menu').addClass('is-open');
      $('.menu').addClass('is-active');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I just put this code in my js file ? ... it doesn't work :/ I maybe forgot something ...